# What does "I do real" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "I do real" mean in this context?

> I do real, I do family, I do Jesus.

Comment: Please tell us where you saw this line.

Comment: It seems to mean “realism, family and Jesus are important to me”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means something like "realism, family and Jesus are important to me".

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/do?s=t) currently shows 36 definitions of the word "do". However, in the vernacular of certain parts of middle America, especially southern, rural, country, or farming areas, that number of definitions is not considered a constraint or limiting factor to the nearly infinite number of applications of the word. "do" means both everything and nothing. Overusing "do" might sometimes be done unconsciously, and other times (such as your example) to highlight one's membership in this demographic.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it really helps!